# How to resize/style the HTML content in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How to resize/style the HTML content? for example, I want to make the HTML content small. currently, when I try to wrap parse(htmlContent) into a div and give it height and width it's not making the HTML content small. How to fix it?

```
<div>
  <h1>HTML Content</h1>
  <div style={{ width: '50%' }}>
    {parse(htmlContent)}
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using html-react-parser https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser and what I am trying to do is display any website in my React app like we would use iFrame but a lot of websites don't support it so I am doing view page source anding the html content in parse function.

So can anyone help me resize it so that I can make it small

Answer (score 0):

try using tailwind library for react
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

and then use this:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/resize

Comment: It's not working, size is not changing